# Bitbucket ssh test returns `remote: ssh_exchange_identification: read: Operation timed out`

Tags: git, ssh, mercurial, bitbucket

I am setting up a new machine and in doing so, was trying to pull repos from bitbucket, which does not work for either git or hg. I have added my public key to bitbucket.

This is what I see when I run the debugging command that bitbucket suggests in the troubleshooting guide:

```
$ ssh -Tv hg@bitbucket.org
OpenSSH_6.9p1, LibreSSL 2.1.8
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/toadjamb/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to bitbucket.org [104.192.143.2] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/therrick2/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /Users/therrick2/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type 5
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.9
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Operation timed out
```

Comment: I have the same problem and it's probably related to what they say on  http://status.bitbucket.org/ . Basically "Call tech support if you have problems with push or pull".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the ip address needed to be whitelisted.

At the time that I posted this question I didn't realize the network was locked down that tightly.