# Could not read from a remote repository when publishing my site

Tags: reactjs, git, github, github-pages, docusaurus

I am using ***docusaurus*** to write a documentation website for a product. I made some customizations to the site and try to publish it on GitHub.

Following the tutorial, I config the `website/siteConfig.js`, ran `npm run build` and used :

```
$ GIT_USER=<GIT_USER> CURRENT_BRANCH=master USE_SSH=true npm run publish-gh-pages
```

to push it to Github.  Cloning to gh-pages fails and shows "fatal: Could not read from remote repository." error.

The following git commands were what I used.

```
LM-SHC-16507799:website benshi$ ls

README.md   core        node_modules    sidebars.json   yarn.lock
blog        git     package.json    siteConfig.js
build       i18n        pages       static
LM-SHC-16507799:website benshi$ pwd

/Users/user_name/Desktop/calender/week_3/docusaurus-exp/website

LM-SHC-16507799:website user_name$ GIT_USER=my_github_user_name CURRENT_BRANCH=master USE_SSH=true npm run publish-gh-pages
```

It failed. The following error messages were shown.

```
> @ publish-gh-pages /Users/user_name/Desktop/calender/week_3/docusaurus-exp/website
> docusaurus-publish

master
https://github.com/my_github_user_name/docusaurus-exp.git
generate.js triggered...
feed.js triggered...
feed.js triggered...
sitemap.js triggered...
Without `from` option PostCSS could generate wrong source map and will not find Browserslist config. Set it to CSS file path or to `undefined` to prevent this warning.
Site built successfully. Generated files in 'build' folder.
89b1f1bd2f7e2403a08a194a89379916edcbb540
Cloning into 'docusaurus-exp-gh-pages'...
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Operation timed out
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
Error: git clone failed
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ publish-gh-pages: `docusaurus-publish`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ publish-gh-pages script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/user_name/.npm/_logs/2019-07-18T07_15_37_998Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bitbucket ssh test returns \`remote: ssh\_exchange\_identification: read: Operation timed out\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37844777/bitbucket-ssh-test-returns-remote-ssh-exchange-identification-read-operation)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+ssh_exchange_identification%3A+read%3A+Operation+timed+out

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a Docusaurus issue.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is not related with Docusaurus indeed.

The error was cause when I tried to publish the site tp `gh-pages branch` with `USE_SSH=true`. In fact I don't have SSH stored on this machine. The issue was resolved by romoving this parameter (or set `USE_SSH=false`).